# stringsasfactors=FALSE equivalent in sqlfetch r

Tags: r

I have a RODBC connection using odbcConnect to a DB.
I am reading in a table into a variable.

This table has a text column, however when I submit a subset on the text column, I get a factor.
I am looking for a stringsasfactors=FALSE equivalent while reading a table using RODBC.
Any thoughts on how I might be able to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please include some example code: would help to see the function used to read the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eg the `stringsAsFactors` option to sqlQuery.  Documentation is eg [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-14/topics/sqlQuery).

Modifying the basic example from the help page:

```
channel <- odbcConnect("test")
sqlSave(channel, USArrests, rownames = "State", verbose = TRUE)
options(dec=".") # optional, if DBMS is not locale-aware or set to ASCII
## note case of State, Murder, Rape are DBMS-dependent,
## and some drivers need column and table names double-quoted.
sqlQuery(channel, paste("select State, Murder from USArrests",
                         "where Rape > 30 order by Murder"),
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)   ## your option here
close(channel)
```

As `sqlFetch()` passes arguments through via `...`, it will work the same way.  Just add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, or even set it globally via `options()`.